# How can i scroll a parent div, where the childs child divs are overflowing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

So, i have some code that looks roughly like this:

```css
.Overview {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.OverviewResourceHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid none solid solid;
}

.OverviewResourceTypeHead {
  width: 40%;
  border-style: none solid none none;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 53px;
}

.OverviewResourceHead {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.OverviewTimeHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red red red red;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
.OverviewDays{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 17px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    
}

.OverviewDay{
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.OverviewWeeks{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 17px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.OverviewWeek{
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

.OverviewMonths{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.Overview31Month{
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 620px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Overview30Month{
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Overview">
  <div class="OverviewResourceHeader">
    <div class="OverviewResourceTypeHead">Type</div>
    <div class="OverviewResourceHead">Resource</div>
  </div>
  <div class="OverviewTimeHeader">
    <div class="OverviewMonths">
      <div class="Overview31Month">October 2017</div>
      <div class="Overview30Month">November 2017</div>
      <div class="Overview31Month">December 2017</div>
    </div>
    <div class="OverviewWeeks">
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 39</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 40</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 41</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 42</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 43</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 44</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 45</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 46</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 47</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 48</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 49</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 50</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 51</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 52</div>
    </div>
    <div class="OverviewDays">
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

the element with the OverviewTimeHeader css class has three child divs, which are all overflowed by their child elements, with overflow:hidden on them, so as not to have three scrollbars. I need to be able to scroll overviewTimeHeader though, and trying to move the overflow properties around in the css classes has yielded nothing useful to me, so I am starting to wonder if it's even possible. I've also tried to use the jquery-mousewheel plugin, but it seems that it's not possible to scroll elements with hidden overflow, so I am quite at a loss for how to handle this. I think css would be preferrable, but i haven't been able to manage anything close to it.

(don't mind the missing alignment of the days and the weeks, It works in the more complete model i have, that's not the issue at all)

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to achieve. For a start you say that `OverviewResourceHeader` has 3 child divs that overflow etc... but it doesn't, it only has 2 divs that look like they are just headings.

Comment: No, I say that OverviewTimeHeader has 3 child divs, which it does.

Well, to elaborate you can see both the weeknumbers, months and weekdays "overflowing" out the right side. That's fine, but i would like to be able to scroll through them (along the x-axis). did that make it any clearer? :)

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the class names. Its still not clear what you want though... what exactly do you want to be able to scroll, e.g. do you want everything to display as normal and have your outer div be the only one that scrolls, or do you need any of your child divs to scroll inside the container div (which now also scrolls)?

Comment: I added red borders to the bit i want to scroll along the x-axis. I would like to be able to do this just as if it was a div with a simple collection of div children with display: inline-block set on it.

Any Clearer? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? If so, you only need one scroll - on your `OverviewTimeHeader` class:

```
.OverviewTimeHeader {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    /* rest of your styles here */
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
.Overview {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* overflow-x: auto;  */
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/* ADD THIS TO CLEAR THE FLOATS */
.Overview:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.OverviewResourceHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid none solid solid;
}

.OverviewResourceTypeHead {
  width: 40%;
  border-style: none solid none none;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 53px;
}

.OverviewResourceHead {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.OverviewTimeHeader {
  overflow-x: scroll;   /* ADDED THIS */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.OverviewDays{
    /* overflow-x: hidden;  */
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 17px;
    /* overflow-y:hidden; */
    
}

.OverviewDay{
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    
}

.OverviewWeeks{
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: none solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 17px;
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}

.OverviewWeek{
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    
}

.OverviewMonths{
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.Overview31Month{
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 620px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Overview30Month{
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px;
    border-style: none solid none none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Overview">
  <div class="OverviewResourceHeader">
    <div class="OverviewResourceTypeHead">Type</div>
    <div class="OverviewResourceHead">Resource</div>
  </div>
  <div class="OverviewTimeHeader">
    <div class="OverviewMonths">
      <div class="Overview31Month">October 2017</div>
      <div class="Overview30Month">November 2017</div>
      <div class="Overview31Month">December 2017</div>
    </div>
    <div class="OverviewWeeks">
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 39</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 40</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 41</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 42</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 43</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 44</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 45</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 46</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 47</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 48</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 49</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 50</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 51</div>
      <div class="OverviewWeek">Week 52</div>
    </div>
    <div class="OverviewDays">
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">M</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">W</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">T</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">F</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
      <div class="OverviewDay">S</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've commented out the `overflow`s I removed so you can see what I changed.

You also need a "clearfix" for your floated divs (which I've added), and you have some divs (e.g. OverviewResourceHeader) that have a float and inline-block - once you float it, the `inline-block` won't apply anymore so you don't need both.

Comment: This is exactly what i meant. Is there a clever a clever way to hide the scrollbar?
And would i just use jquery-mousewheel to make it scroll when i use the mousewheel?

Comment: @user3801839 You had so many hidden overflows in your code that I thought it had to be something else, because all you really needed was one! :) If you want to do things like hide the scrollbar and use the mousewheel, then you would have to look at Javascript. But I'd be hesitant about doing that because its not intuitive to users - its better for usability to give visual clues so they know they can scroll... otherwise they might not realise and think your site is broken :)

Comment: I completely agree, But there will be numbers underneath with a different scrollable area, and the two will need to be synchronized in their scrolling, so it should really be no problem to only display the one at the very bottom.

But I'll try and see if i can find a solution i like for it. About the hidden stuff, i actually thought i had tried this very approach once before, but apparently not. Thanks very much for the assistance, FluffyKitten.

Comment: In that case you will definitely need javascript. Good luck with it!